# path compatible for both windows and linux

Tags: python, windows

so my current folder structure is:

```
my_project/scr/codefile.py
          /logs/
```

I have a code(below) in codefile.py that writes to folder 'logs', it works fine on linux and returns OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument on Windows

```
import datetime
from os.path import dirname, abspath, join, exists
logs_folder = join(dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__))), 'logs')
file_name = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")+'.csv'
with open(join(logs_folder, file_name), 'w') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter = "\n")
    writer.writerow(list_input)
```

Comment: On Windows, filenames can't have colons `:`

Comment: Why would you store logs by the exact second?

Comment: thanks, John Gordon,  that helped me
OneCricketeer, I just wanted for them to be unique and wanted to finish it fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the filename timestamp format since in Windows OS filenames can't contain colons `:` as mentioned in comments by John Gordon
So instead of

```py
import datetime
from os.path import dirname, abspath, join, exists
logs_folder = join(dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__))), 'logs')
file_name = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")+'.csv'
with open(join(logs_folder, file_name), 'w') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter = "\n")
    writer.writerow(list_input)
```

Try using

```py
import datetime
from os.path import dirname, abspath, join, exists
logs_folder = join(dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__))), 'logs')
file_name = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H_%M_%S")+'.csv'
with open(join(logs_folder, file_name), 'w') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter = "\n")
    writer.writerow(list_input)
```